# Android support screen design

Tags: android

I know about supporting multiple screens in Android and I use it in my app. But supporting different screen sizes and DPI makes your application size large. We all know about the 50mb file size limit in Google Play right? So, is it possible to create a folder like the following?

```
\layout-small-160
\layout-normal-240
```

If that is not possible do any one here knows how to support multiple screen sizes and its DPI's without using too much image to make my application size smaller?

Comment: you can create multiple apk for multiple screens and load it in play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only give my suggestion and you can try it.

By default, we have three drawable folder drawable-ldpi(120), drawable-mdpi(160), drawable-hdpi(240).

When the App need image, Android will find the image according to the screen destiny. Obviously, the image in drawable-ldpi folder is fit if the app running on phone which have a low destiny.

But if there is no image in drawable-ldpi folder. Android will find if there is image in drawable-hdpi. If it exists, android will scale the image(0.5) and show it.

So you don't need to prepare images for every destiny. You only need to prepare the image for hdpi scrren. And for some individual images which demand accurate size, you need to prepare for the three destiny.

You could download some famous APK and extract them.Then enter the res folder to check how the author did.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You could download the Skype.apk(The Skype Android package) and extract it. You can see the res folder. You could check how the Skype client developer solve it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article of Android documentation:

```
To optimize your application's UI for the different screen sizes and densities, you can provide alternative resources for any of the generalized sizes and densities. Typically, you should provide alternative layouts for some of the different screen sizes and alternative bitmap images for different screen densities. At runtime, the system uses the appropriate resources for your application, based on the generalized size or density of the current device screen.
```

Therefore, yes it is possible to create folders for different layouts as you mentioned in your question. The following is a good practice of having your resources folder organized for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Yet, you do not need to provide alternative resources for every combination of screen size and density. The system provides robust compatibility features that can handle most of the work of rendering your application on any device screen, if you develop your application following the instructions described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence).

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions:

1. Resize the images to be exactly the size you need. Use proper compression (use a professional application to edit the images, like photoshop, that optimize the image and compress it well).
2. Put part of the images on an external server and download all on the first use. Downloading the images from the server has the advantage that you know the device size, so you can download only the relevant sizes.

Comment: I don;t understand what stuff don;t like?

Answer (score 0):

Case close.. It is posible to create a folder that has two modifier..

like this

layout-normal-hdpi    ----  this will only set the view from specific phone that has 240 dpi and normal screen

thanks for all who commented and give an idea here..